# start using jpa in spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, jpa

Im really dont get it. I download STS Spring Tool Suite, and i want to use JPA in my MVC app. I have to add some JAR's? where can i find that JAR's, how do i know what JAR's are? what i have to add to my pom.xml file?

I already checked many sites but anyone tell exactly how to make it work. Its like the assume you know some steps that i really dont know what steps are.

Then, if i create more than one repository for differents objects, they do the transactions to the same database?

Answer (score 0):

use this in pom.xml

`<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: i write that in pom.xml and thats it?

Comment: yep...and just do a maven build after that, so that it downloads the dependency, and javax.persistence  is ready to use.

Comment: how do i build maven? can you explain step by step what are you trying to explain?

Comment: here is a 1min video that i just now created with steps... http://screencast.com/t/hTGvUzdBl

Comment: now its very clear...the thing was to add the dependency at pom.xml file and compile the projects. When you compile, appears the jar files needed automatically in Maven Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend visiting http://mvnrepository.com. I have used that in the past to find out what I need to add to the POM. Also, IDEs like IntelliJ and Eclipse make this really easy by providing arch-types, etc. For example, to get spring go here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context/4.1.0.RELEASE.

Here is something to get your started. Just add these dependencies and you'll get jpa along with spring. Removing the persistence this is what you would need to make a simple spring mvc web server. With the persistence, you'll have to set things up.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Is there any way of doing this automatically with out adding by hand this dependencies?

Comment: Unless you use a predefined arch-type, you'll have to do it by hand. IntelliJ is really good at this, because it has code hinting when you edit the POM file to show you jars it knows about so it can save you time searching the internet. Eclipse only supports arch-types. I recommend getting IntelliJ, the community edition supports this for free. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: i dont get it. I download an example for the oficial web of Spring, i import to STS and works perfectly. Is there any chance you can explain me exactly what i have to do. 

I know you are trying to help me, but when im lost and somebody gaves me new url to visit, to read is difficult. I dont believe that is a complicate thing. It must be easier than this. 

1 - where can i find de JARS that i need?
2 - is there any place that maybe the project will download automatically?
3 - in STS is any especial type of project?

Man, it might be easier.

Comment: In my opinion I would avoid using the Spring Tool Suite. There are a few things you need to do with Maven: (1) install maven to your computer, (2) create a MAVEN_HOME environmental variable that points to the maven installation (i.e. C:\maven\apache-maven-3.0.4), and then (3) create the POM file. Calling mvn with the build directive where the pom file is located will automatically download the jar files for you. That is the beauty of maven. Using the free version of IntelliJ makes this even easier because it integrated, Eclipse has a maven project as well.

Comment: Why you would avoid using Spring Tool Suite?

Comment: It's mostly personal preference. I find IntelliJ easier to use. I tried it a few years back and made no progress setting up a spring mvc project using JPA but switched over to Eclipse and it was real easy (using maven plugin with web tool kit). Recently I used IntelliJ and it was even easier. Both options are free alternatives as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of example on the net. I'm sure if you searched you could find something. Anyway I have a project here you can use to get started:

https://github.com/alanhay/spring-data-jpa-bootstrap

This is a minimal project that has everything you need including some unit tests that will run against an in-memory HSQLDB database.

You can download the ZIP and import to Eclipse/STS or check it out as a git project. For the ZIP:

- download, unzip and then in Eclipse/STS select Import > Existing Maven Project > Select the unzipped folder.
- Once imported right click on the project and run mvn > install (because the project uses QueryDSL requires a full Maven build rather than Eclipse incremental build but there is a plugin you can setup).
- Open the test class UserRepositoryTest and run.

Also, further to the comments above, the persistence-api is just a specification. You also need to add dependency for an implementation e.g. Hibernate, OpenJPA, EclipseLink. My example project uses Hibernate.

Comment: thanks you. I was testing the persistence-api and i realized that something was left. I have to use JPA with MVC. Is there any tip, project you did or site to read about it?